# How to convert a select query into a stored function?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a function to show details of driver having the particular shift...

```
select driver.driver_no,driver_name,licence_no,address,d_age,salary from driver,bus_driver as bd where bd.shift='2' and bd.driver_no = driver.driver_no;
```

Display the rows....
I want a function to display them taking shift as input

Comment: Don't use a cross join here, use an [inner join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join).

Comment: What have you tried so far to create the stored function for this query? What is the result you get for each attempt you have made? What are the error messages you get when you try to create the stored function?

Comment: @Progman I've tried returning the select statement using varchar(128).But I get an error that Operand should contain column(s) ...

Comment: @DeepakPawade Please [edit] your question to include the full SQL statement you try to run to create the stored function and add the full complete error message you get when you try.